# How to use strings instead of numbers in a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I am using [bootstrap slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) and I am doing:

```
Days: <b>1</b> <input id="days" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="31" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,31]"/> <b>31</b>
```

launching it with `$("#days").slider({});`

That works but what if I wanted to create a slider for months, using strings not numbers?

```
Months: <b>January</b> <input id="months" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2017" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[January, February, March]"/> <b>March</b>
```

launching it with `$("#months").slider({});`

That gives:

> Error: Invalid input value '[January, February, March]' passed in

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1282/)

Comment: Please create a fiddle with little bit more code...

Comment: @Shiladitya sure, updated the question with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1286/

```js
    $("#days, #years, #months").slider({
      tooltip: 'always'
    });
```

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick-label-container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row" id="time" >
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        Days: <b>1</b> <input id="days" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="31" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,31]"/> <b>31</b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        Months: <input id="months" type="text" class="span2" value="" 
          data-slider-min="1" 
          data-slider-max="12"
          data-slider-step="1" 
          data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["January", "February", "March"]' />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        Years: <b>0</b> <input id="years" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2017" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,2017]"/> <b>Today</b>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Reference:** http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/ . Check example 19.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @NisargShah ... Nothing like that... You are really the best. :)

Comment: @Shiladitya how would we hide those texts with the slider? And how to show the months in the tooltip? And finally I wouldn't want the circles but just a straight line as per the other sliders?

Comment: fixed but I still don't know how to show the months and not the number in the slider https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1308/

Comment: @rob.m .. Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1315/

Comment: @Shiladitya thanks a lot, any how we can have the range for the months too?

Comment: @rob.m ..Here you go with the updated solution https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1316/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151152/discussion-between-rob-m-and-shiladitya).